# time split to constant daily intervals and summarise the results

Tags: r, time, split

I have a data frame contains `time` variable of object `POSIXct` in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`.

I've been able to split it into time intervals using: `split(dfrm, cut((dfrm$time), "30 mins"))`

However, this method starts the splitting from the minimum `time` value I have in my data; but, I'm interested in splitting the data to daily time intervals, and summarise the results whitin each time interval.

Here is some reproducible example (sorry for the "poor" example; I can't copy and paste right now):

```
dfrm <- data.frame(time=as.POSIXct(c("2017-02-01 00:58:53", "2017-02-01 00:53:02","2017-02-01 01:15:09","2017-02-01 02:28:08","2017-02-01 02:15:20","2017-02-01 02:37:25")))
```

So, using my splitting method mentioned above, I'll get 4 groups starts at `00:53:00` with intervals of 30 minutes (and the data will be splitted between 3 of that 4 groups with 3,1 and 2 observations). While I'm looking for something like that:

```
Interval         Total rows
1                       0
2                       2
3                       1
4                       0
5                       2
6                       1
7                       0
8                       0
.
.
```

where `1` is for `00:00:00-00:30:00`, 2 is for `00:30:00-01:00:00`,..., 48 is for `23:30:00-00:00:00`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output based on that

Comment: See [mcve] and [ask] on how to ask a question.

Comment: @akrun.. can you have a look at my updated post. I added some reproducible example. Thank you in advance!