# Spliting date/time data into constant time intervals

Tags: r, datetime, time, split, cut

I already posted similar question here:
[time split to constant daily intervals and summarise the results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44047943/7133402)

Now I'm trying it in a simple version:

I have a data which contains `date/time` variable (call it `x`) of object `POSIXct` in the following format: `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`.

The `date` is not really of my interest. What I'm trying to do is to split my `time` data into *constant* time intervals.

To make it clear, let's start with some reproducible example. Using `dput`, my `x` variable looks like:

```
structure(c(1495608914, 1495642528, 1495642529, 1495607831, 1495641488, 1495643715), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone="")
```

I've been able to split it into time intervals using: `split(x, cut((x), "30 mins"))`

However, this method starts the splitting from the minimum `time` value I have in `x`; but, I'm interested in splitting the data to *constant* time intervals.

So, using my *splitting* method mentioned above, I'll get 20 groups starts at `06:37:00` with intervals of 30 minutes (and `x` will be splitted between 3 of that 20 groups with 2,1 and 3 observations). While I'm looking for some indication regarding the data point time interval:

```
x                   v1   v2    . . . x.ind
06:37:11                             14
06:55:14                             14
15:58:08                             32
.
.
.
```

where 1 is for `00:00:00-00:30:00`, 2 is for `00:30:00-01:00:00`,..., 14 is for `06:30:00-07:00:00`,..., 48 is for `23:30:00-00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using dplyr for the join and grouping and lubridate for date rounding `floor_date`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

observations <- data.frame(period = floor_date(x, unit = "30 minutes"), n=rep(1, length(x)))
intervals <- data.frame(period = seq.POSIXt(min(observations), max(observations), by = 30*60))

result <- intervals %>%
  full_join(observations) %>%
  group_by(period) %>%
  summarize(n=sum(n,na.rm= TRUE))
```

Comment: Running the "observation" code row gives me the following error: `Error in match.arg(unit) : arg should be one of "second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "quarter"`.. Can you estimate why is it?

Comment: Sorry I pasted older code - variable"xr"  should be `observations` within the min and max. I edited the answer (but haven't tested)